# Cache user specific application data with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In our microservice each authenticated Spring Security user has an associated application-specific data structure. 
when thinking on how can we easily cache this data together with the user, we thought it would be good if it could have been done similar to this:

1. add the cached data to the in-memory-authentication when creating the users:

   ```
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
       auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123").roles("ROLE");
       auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").cache(appDate);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. pull the data in @RestController methods:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/foo")
   public void foo() {    
       User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
       Object details = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();    
       Object cachedAppDate= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCachedData();    
   }
   ```

Obviously the method in bold are a wish-list and do not exist.
Any advice on how to do this easily with the existing Spring Security framework?

thanks!

Comment: I think you can set cache as the detail to authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your cached data using only user name (no password required) you can use implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`, it has only one method - `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)`, and return required data as custom UserDetail object. After implement interface, just pass it as UserDetailService for AuthenticationManagerBuilder.

If you need password to get that cached data, things got a bit complicated. 
You should create your own AuthenticationProvider and put cached data in Principal or UserDetails. For example code for set additional data in Principal:

```
public class MyProvider implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        ... // check login/password

        Object cachedAppDate = "i'm cached data!";
        MyUser user = new MyUser(token, cachedData); 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken output = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, authentication.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
        output.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
        return output;
    }

}

public static class MyUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

        private final Object cachedData;

        public User(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token, Object cachedData) {
            super(token.getName(), "", token.getAuthorities());
            this.cachedData = cachedData;
        }

        public Object getCachedData() {
            return this.cachedData;
        }
    }
```

and access cached data as `((MyUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getCachedData();`